# Sequelize: Create join table attribute with set<Association>

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am working with Sequelize 4.38.0 and I have a problem with the belongsToMany association.

I defined my tables like this:

```
const Role = db.define('role', {
  name: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
  standard: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false}
})

const Privilege = db.define('privilege', {
  id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
  description: {type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: false}
})

const RolePrivilege = db.define('rolePrivileges', {
  restriction: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true}
})

Privilege.belongsToMany(Role, {through: RolePrivilege})
Role.belongsToMany(Privilege, {through: RolePrivilege})
```

So the code says that a privilege can have many roles, a role can also have many privileges - so it is a n:m association.

Like you saw above I created that association through the table `RolePrivilege` which has an additional attribute `restriction`.

When I want to add privileges to roles I usually do it like this:

```
Role.build({id: role}).setPrivileges(privileges)
```

where `privileges` is just an array of privilege ID's.
So i now want to fill the `restriction` field in the join table (`RolePrivileges`) to a special value **for each privilege** to role association.

So I tried the following like it described [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html)

```
privileges = privileges.map(p => {
    const priv = Privilege.build({id: p})
    priv.rolePrivileges.restriction = 'a'
    return priv
  })
```

and did the same query like above. But it throws the error that setting `restriction` on undefined is not possible. After a long google session I tried including the association table on the `build` method, but it still did not work.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the errors still sits in front of the screen.
I read the documentation wrong.

Instead of writing the following:

```
priv.rolePrivileges.restriction = 'a'
```

I just had to create the association object before:

```
priv.rolePrivileges = {
  restriction: 'a'
}
```

Maybe I could help someone with this.